# Linux Kernel on TCP and SCTP

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, sctp

I want to research the transport layer protocol of SCTP. Is it possible to replace the tcp with sctp in linux kernel and  That applications can send messages via sctp transparently? After Googled, I did not get some information on this topic. But, I think it is possible, because sctp is the superset of tcp. Could anyone give me some instruction or materials on it?

Add at UTC+8 7:57P.M
Thank you all. I am sorry to talk wrongly. I mean I want to modify the linux kernel, enabling applications which used to transport by TCP to use SCTP transparently without any change of the application itself. So, the key point is patching the kernel. But, I don't know what to do.

Comment: I believe that recent Linux kernels do support `SCTP` already.

Comment: Recent version of Linux support SCTP, to access it use libSCTP, which is a user-space access to Linux Kernel SCTP

Comment: You need to patch the application source code so when it creates a TCP socket with e.g. `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)` you replace it with `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have modified the question. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @nrathaus I have updated the question. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @nos I have updated the question. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ability is already provided by the [withsctp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/withsctp.1.html) tool. It is part of the standard SCTP supporting tools on linux, [lksctp-tools](http://lksctp.sourceforge.net/), and works by hooking existing binaries to use SCTP sockets instead of TCP sockets.

Answer (score 2):

> I think it is possible because SCTP is [a] superset of TCP.

You are mistaken. SCTP is not a superset of TCP[1]. Ergo it is not possible.

[1] http://porky.linuxjournal.com:8080/LJ/161/9748.html

Comment: I updated the question. The main point is how to modify the kernel, to make the applications tranport via SCTP transparently without any change of application layer app. And the link[1] is useful. Thx a lot

Comment: @nos So, you mean that I can modified the source code of lib of socket, cheating apps?